# Call to a member function setCookie() on null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes estoy usando Laravel 5.6 y acabo de aplicar middleware a mis rutas este hace el filtrado de la siguiente manera:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $tipoUsuario=$this->auth->user()->id_role;

    if ($tipoUsuario!=1) {
        return view('denied');
        }
    return $next($request); 

}
```

Pero el sistema me responde con el error:

> Call to a member function setCookie() on null

Comment: Tuve un error similar, no se si sea el caso, pero intenta borrando las cookies de tu navegador.

Answer (score 2):

El archivo de `Middleware` no tiene alcance a los recursos.

Te recomiendo que declares una ruta en el archivo `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/denied', ['as' => 'denied', function() {
    return view('denied');
}]);
```

Y en el archivo `Middleware` algo como lo siguiente:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $tipoUsuario = $this->auth->user()->id_role;

    if ($tipoUsuario != 1) {
        return redirect()->route('denied');
    }

    return $next($request); 
}
```